# How can I type a helper function parameter using WritableDraft from @reduxjs/toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, reducers, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I'm using `@reduxjs/toolkit` and I'd like to write a helper function for one of my slice reducers.

Something I would call like this:

```
reducers: {
  MY_REDUCER(draft, action) {
    helperFunction(draft);
  }
}
```

This would be the helper function:

```
const helperFunction= (
  draft: WritableDraft<MY_STATE_TYPE>
) : void => {
  // CHANGE draft
};
```

[image]

But I'm not being able to type the `draft` parameter. The `WritableDraft` type does not seem to be available from `@reduxjs/toolkit`. Is this possible? How can I do this?

`@reduxjs/toolkit` uses `WritableDraft<MY_STATE_TYPE>`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like either immer recently renamed that or your IDE is just leaking an immer-internal name. Try the `Draft` type, which is what RTK is actually using.

Comment: Yeah, `Draft` seems to work. It also works if I use my state type directly. Since those types are "identical" as far as containing the properties I'm allowed to update. But I'll use `Draft` to keep it more consistent. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, those would only differ if your state contained readonly stuff.